# Generating random length keys without any overlap

Tags: sql, database, data-processing

I want to create a key for my members with following rules:

- Each key may be between 4 and 8 characters.
- Each key exclude other secondary greater length keys with prefix of it.
- No lower-length key may be generated according to second rule.

As an example:

Suppose we have following keys: `1212`, `1213`, `019393` and `0793993`

We can't create the key `0193` because of the third key in above and also we can't create key `12125` because of the first key in above.

So, this is the problem:
What is the best way to generate a new key according the rules with lowest process load?

1. One solution is to check all generated keys each time, but it may be
   time-consuming.
2. Another solution is to store the excluded keys in a table and check every time if there is an excluded key in the table to not register for a member, but it may be storage and time consuming.

What do think about the best solution for implementation of the problem?

Comment: Is hashing a solution?

Comment: I think the best solution is to use a numeric `IDENTITY` column on the table and have the database generate unique keys for you. Natural keys are tricky to implement correctly. If you must implement a natural key, I would still have an `IDENTITY` column on the table, then build the `IDENTITY` into the natural key to guarantee uniqueness.